# Action<string> not garbage collected. Why?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Can't seem to get Action collected by GC. Why?

```
        WeakReference reference = null;
        WeakReference reference2 = null;

        new Action(() =>
        {
            Action<string> deliveryMessage = (ans) => { };
            object a = new object();

            reference = new WeakReference(deliveryMessage);
            reference2 = new WeakReference(a);
        }) ();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Assert.Null(reference2.Target);  //True
        Assert.Null(reference.Target);   //False
```

I'm going to use Action in a WeakReference list, but I need to this simple test to go through first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lambda expression does not use any captured variables so it is transformed into a static method. As an optimization, to prevent additional GC overhead caused by allocations, a static delegate field is also created. This static field is accessed when the assignment is executed. A new delegate is not created each time. This static delegate, once initialized, will never be collected. You can see this by viewing the [decompilation](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayZshQoDqqKgGsASqgBmqAE6oIpVDAO6DRkwF4YEYESI5FbFeq3nDx0zv2fUAJhgbOwcceQUIVAB3GABBUmQwPggxSSCAPnDZFmcFeMTkgB4UPUgodJhBVBIefQQRVFoqKGsYMSoIECkrCqYYAF8nXPY+AgArVASYKiDbaJhRiYTJMOH2M19LWciY100fC2MxKpq6hqaWiSG1jcOA7fm9902jqius9n6pFfD+7H6gAA=).

Comment: Thanks! Adding `Action<string> deliveryMessage = TestMethod;` fixed my problem.